# Looking for annotating vector editor

Tags: java, python, vector-graphics

I'm looking for a 2D vector graphics editor that can tag/annotate objects.  I want to load the files into python+tkinter or java+SWT canvas (other GUI toolkits could also work).  Then I want to uses the tags to have the program animate things like color, on/off, line type, etc.

I need it to run on Linux and Windows.  The editor should be usable by non-programmers.

XFIG is about the right capability, but I don't see a way to tag objects with extra information.  I might be able to extend one of these programs (but I would rather be lazy :-): tkpaint, tkdraw, ClasyTk, tykwa.

I haven't look seriously at SVG because I don't want/need to deal with splines.  DXF might be an option, but I'm not sure how complicated that would be to parse.

Thanks,
-Dan

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape. You can edit the SVG to add tags (from within the program).

There are existing SVG → SWT Canvas toolkits, so, no need to reinvent the wheel, I'd expect.

Comment: That's an interesting option.  Inkscape lets you set a title and a (multi-line) description for each object.  I wish Dia did the same thing.  It's interface is closer to my needs.

Comment: one can also add arbitrary XML (e.g. namespaced attributes) to the SVG; depending upon your parser, you can collect these when you read the file. `<svg:element myns:attribute="value" …` type of thing…